# Running db migrations in bg thread before any Activity is launched

Tags: android

I need to run database migrations asynchronously in a bg thread. 
However, I do not know how to do it in my `Application::onCreate()` before any application's activity will be launched. I can handle the migration in some splash activity, but there is a problem what about deeplinks that lead directly into other specific activities.

So, what is the solution?

1. Run db migration in bg thread before any activity is launched. I fear this is not possible, is it?
2. Run db migraiton in a custom splash screen activity. Is this correct (a good approarch) to direct all the deeplinks directly into the splash activity and reroute them after a migration?
3. Another solution

--

Edit: 
Also, how does the solution 2. play with BroadcastReceiver? There will be no activity :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are right, it's not possible.
2. This seems to be the only choice you have if the db migration absolutely must be done before your users get to the main activities of your app.